# All document properties exported to single string field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

I am using the Firebase Extension for BigQuery.
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export

The document data that shows up in big query is all crammed into one string field called data.
This is not usable as I can't query on it.

If I import the data from a firestore export or backup it comes in as expected with each document property in its own field.

**Any ideas on how to get the Firebase Extension for BigQuery to work the same as transferring data from an export?**

**Data from Extension**

```
SELECT * FROM `qmtbc-dev.qmtbc_dev_export.members_raw_latest`
```

[image: Data from Extension]

**Data from Export/Backup**

```
SELECT * FROM `qmtbc-dev.qmtbc_dev_export.membersExport`
```

[image: Data from Export/Backup]

**EDIT:**

It would be good to know if this is by design or something I have not set up correctly in the configuration.

Comment: @Rob  It is a result set. How on earth am I meant to put the text from that in the question without it looking like rubbish?

Comment: The data itself is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok. As long we can understand it from the question without the image I guess it's OK.

Comment: It is a String but not any String it is a JSON, try with UNNEST https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions

Comment: @cutiko Thanks that looks useful.  I will give it a try if I don't get a solution.  I would have thought the extension would have done this part automatically.  This table is populated real time (trigger from firestore) so I would have to set up a job to run a script and export it to another table regularly.  Seems like a lot of work that I would have expected handled already.

Comment: @MadMac where you able to make it work?

Comment: @Nahuel Varela  Not yet I am still waiting to see what the stackoverflow net drags in.  I made a functionality request here: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/113#issuecomment-555537246

Comment: @MadMac was the information on the Github issue working for you?

Comment: @NahuelVarela yes it seems to work.  I will put a full answer up once I have time to test it further.